# how do i write a query in access to update a column based on the values of 2 other columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I'm using access to update a table (not by choice). The table looks like this:

[image: sample table]

I want to populate the last column ("regulation 102 or Regulation 103") with

- "Reg 102 only" if only Reg 102 non-compliance appears in the "regulation for non-compliance" column for each inspection ID,
- "Reg 103 only" if only Reg 103 non-compliance appears in the "regulation for non-compliance" column for each inspection ID
- "Reg 102 and 103" if both appear.

So in the picture above, there are 3 inspections – the first inspection (1-JHHK9) would be Reg 102 only and the 2nd/3rd (1-JJVAN, 1-JJVFR) would be both Reg 102 and 103.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and a `join`:

```
select t.*,
       switch(cnt_102 > 0 and cnt_103 > 0, "Reg 102 and 103",
              cnt_102 > 0, "Reg 102 only",
              cnt_103 > 0, "Reg 103 only",
              1=1, "Neither"
             ) as reg_102_or_103
from t left join
     (select t.[inspection id],
             sum(iif([regulation for non-compliance] like "*Reg102*", 1, 0)) as cnt_102,
             sum(iif([regulation for non-compliance] like "*Reg102*", 1, 0)) as cnt_103
      from t
      group by [inspection id]
     ) as tt
     on t.[inspection id] = tt.[inspection id]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought it didn't work, but there were just some things that were off in the code (a number here, a comma there). But it works! Thanks for everything. This saves me so much time having to do this manually!